# how to split texts in an increasing manner?

Tags: r, text-mining, stringr, stringi, text-chunking

I have a list of texts read into the software using `readtext` library.

```
files <-readtext(paste0(wd), "/r/*.pdf", ignore_missing_files = FALSE, text_field = "texts")
```

The 100 pdf files are of different unequal sizes that vary from 6000 to 40000 words. I need to chunk them in an increasing manner.

```
files.ch <- as.character(files$text)
library(stringi)

chunking <- function(c){
  words.split <- str_split(c, pattern = boundary(type = "word"))
  chunked <- sapply(seq(1000, length(words.split[[1]]), 1000), lapply, function(x) paste(words.split[[1]][1:x], collapse = " "))
  return(chunked)
}
chunked <- lapply(files.ch, chunking)

Error in seq.default(1000, length(words.split[[1]]), 1000) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

here the `by` argument  —length(words.split[[1]]— seems to be problematic. Because the text sizes are not equal, the length of one text won't work for the one which is longer. So, I need to debug this so that the function runs.
I cannot have a fixed `by` value for all the attributes in my list. I need this function to change the `by` value according to the index of the attribute that goes into the function. I mean length(words.split[[1]]) for the first in the list, length(words.split[[2]] for the second and so on. thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: @akrun that just gives us 1000. I want it to produce 1000, 2000, 3000, ..., the last thousand in `length(words.split[[i]])` where `i` is the index of the text put into the function

Comment: why do you have `from` and `to` as 1000

Comment: May be your description is not correct.  Your code `to = length(word.split[[1]])`  instead of `by = length(word.split[[1]])`

Comment: @akrun I need to calculate lexical diversity in the texts with an increasing rate of 1000 words. the function works perfectly on a small sample but with different text sizes, it crashes.

Comment: I modified the function in the solution.  Can you check.  I couldn't test it though

Comment: Can you please confirm by testing.

Comment: @akrun sry to keep you waiting. it doesn't produce the same result as the function above. I want the chunks to be the first 1000 words, the first 2000words, the first 3000 words, and so on. this means the ending extra words that don't fit the chunks need to be removed.